# Aren't MVC principals violated when one uses Interface Builder to create UITabControllers, UINavigationControllers, etc.?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

See title. It feels dirty, but is this the recommended approach?

Comment: What principles can be violated by using IB?

Comment: Assuming I want to follow the MVC design pattern strictly, I thought that controller instantiation shouldn't be the responsibility of the view layer. Unless I'm mistaken, IB is used to create the view (and preferably, the view only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand why you might feel this way, but don't confuse a xib with the view. The xib may contain your View, but the xib itself isn't the view.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't use the interface builder, but as far as I am concerned it doesn't matter how you create the controller. I understand your point, but I wouldn't say that the interface builder's ability to create controllers violates the MVC pattern. It's still MVC, the only thing is that the controllers are created with a tool that you would expect to only create views with.